# Beamer: Include TOC at left side in all slides on a custom theme

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I have a beamer template provided by my university. I want to edit it such that there is a table of content in all slides at the left side.

For simplicity, we can consider a plain template and if anyone helps me on this template, I can build it according to my template.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen the `PaloAlto` theme code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a sidebar, you could use `\useoutertheme{sidebar}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{sidebar}

\begin{document}

\section{bla}
\subsection{blub}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```